Hadoop installation program fails saying "It is not internal or external"
I tried installing Hadoop on my PC, but I failed. When I entered JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17" in cmd, it appears as C:\Program. It is not internal or external by a command, executable program, or batch file.

Which Hadoop installation instructions do you follow? The environment variable JAVA_HOME must be defined with the command line set "JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17" with " left to the variable name and at the end of the folder path or set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17 without ". For an explanation see: Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?
